# Connect iPhone to WAMP server on Windows 10 without wired network

Tags: wireless-networking, iphone, wamp

I'm trying to connect my iPhone to my localhost WAMP connection through the wireless connection on my laptop running Windows 10 personal.

The problem is I don't have a wired internet connection nor a router.

Is there a method to achieve this task?

Comment: Is your WAMP server restricted to localhost? Can you serve the same content via your Wi-Fi connection and then have the iPhone connect to your Windows 10 laptop that way?

Comment: The WAMP server is not restricted to localhost.

I'm currently setting up Apache 2.4.41 on my laptop to accept incoming traffic on port 80, but I'm not sure what the next step would be to access it from my iPhone.

Comment: Not a Windows person, but perhaps if you shared your Internet connection via Wi-Fi and had your iPhone connect to that “hotspot” you could then connect that way? More info [from Microsoft right here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/use-your-pc-as-a-mobile-hotspot-c89b0fad-72d5-41e8-f7ea-406ad9036b85).